# Converting a Stream<int> to Stream<List<String>> in dart

Tags: dart, stream

**tl;dr;**

Looking to convert a `Stream<int>` to a `Stream<List<String>>`.

**Long version:**

I'm new to dart/flutter and this style of programming in general, so pardon me for the noob question.

I'm sending a stream of `char`/`uint8_t` containing ASCII strings over bluetooth. This is received in the form of a `Stream<int>` in a flutter app. I'm looking to split this stream of bytes into lines of strings.

I'm thinking that the approach to this is to convert each int to a character (represented by a string in dart), followed by doing some sort of a split operation on the stream. I could not find good examples of doing a split on a stream, could someone help here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the `Stream` using `transform` and `map`. Here is an example where I use two transformers to get a line of text from my `Stream`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<void> main() async {
  final myStream = Stream.fromIterable(
      [072, 101, 108, 108, 111, 032, 087, 111, 114, 108, 100]);

  print(await myStream
      .map((asciiValue) => String.fromCharCode(asciiValue))
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .first);
  // Hello World
}
```

Should be noted that this code is really not that efficient. Normally, you get multiple `List<int>` events which contains a buffered amount of data and convert a bigger chunk. But since you have a `Stream<int>` this is properly the easiest way to do it where we convert each event to a letter.

Alternative, we can create our own buffered solution. But it really depends on how you get the data.